# Tabu in math mode with squared cells of given size and centered contents

Tags: tables, spacing

How to make in math mode a `tabu` whose cells have fixed height and width, in particular they have to be squared, and such that the content is centered in each cell?

Initially this was my table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor,tabu}

\newcommand\cred[1]{{\color{red}#1}}

\begin{document}

$\begin{tabu}{|c|[1pt]c|c|}
\hline
\cred+ & \cred0 & \cred1 \\
\tabucline[1pt]{-}
\cred0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
\cred1 & 1 & \int_0^1 10 \\
\hline
\end{tabu}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the official [documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf) I read that it is possibile to specify the target **width** of the whole tabular by writing `{tabu} to (dimen)`, but this imply to modify the tabular preamble by using `X[coef,align,type]`. But what about the **height**?

This is the current version of the table

```
$\begin{tabu} to 0.3\textwidth {| X[c] |[1pt] X[c] | X[c] |}
\hline
\cred+ & \cred0 & \cred1 \\
\tabucline[1pt]{-}
\cred0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
\cred1 & 1 & \int_0^1 10 \\
\hline
\end{tabu}$
```

[image]

I don't understand why the colored numbers are so low, and also why the cell containing the integral is broken.

Comment: Before continuing to use tabu read the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about those problems, so is the problem solvable or I have to switch from `tabu` to another environment?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't answer or investigate questions with tabu anymore because of its state.

Comment: Ok I understand, if you know how to solve the problem with `tabular` or something else of your choice I will be pleased to learn it

Comment: As it is your question is about tabu, adapt it if tabular would be ok too.

Comment: You can draw this table with `tikz` using `matrix` library` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let mi elaborate my comment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,
           nodes={draw, minimum size=3em,
                  inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
           column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
           row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
           column 1/.append style={nodes={text=red}},
           row 1/.append style={nodes={text=red}},
           ]
{
+   &   0   &   1   \\
0   &   0   &   1   \\
1   &   1   &   \medint\int_0^1 10 \\ 
}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
if you like coloring column's and row's bacgroun you only need ad `fil=<desired color>` to `col 1/.append style` and `row 1/.append style`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,
           nodes={draw, minimum size=3em,
                  inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
           column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
           row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
           column 1/.append style={nodes={text=red,fill=gray!20}},
           row 1/.append style={nodes={text=red,fill=gray!20}},
           ]
{
+   &   0   &   1   \\
0   &   0   &   1   \\
1   &   1   &   \medint\int_0^1 10 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use `minimum height=4em,` t make the table cells square as the OP requested.

Comment: @leandriis, you are right ... OP wont square cells. I would correct answer asap!

Comment: @Zarko thank you very much, is it possibile to color the background of the column 1 and row 1?

Comment: @soundwave, of course just add `fill=gray!20 to column and row styles. see addendum to my answer.

Comment: @Zarko thank you! is `nccmath` necessary to be able to use math mode inside the table/matrix ?

Comment: @soundwave, no, but it is handy. you can remove it and `\medint` have ugly integral symbol :-(, or replace `\medint` with `displaystyle` and have bigger integral symbol, which will require to increase cells' size (`minimum size=3em` to for example `minimum size=3.4em`)